# Deserialization works on my PC, but fails on another

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am contract serializing and deserializing an object in C#, and it works perfectly on my machine.  However, on a customer machine it throws the following error:

> Unable to deserialize the S:\PriceList.xml
>
> The system returned the message:
>
> Error in line 20 position 19. 'EndElement' 'ConditionalDataSetter' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyCompany.MyModule' is not expected. Expecting element 'Xb45L0rsD'.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataImportConfiguration xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyCompany.MyModule">
    <Comment>59</Comment>
    <Delimiter>44</Delimiter>
    <DisplayType>Round</DisplayType>
    <Escape>34</Escape>
    <ForwardOnly>false</ForwardOnly>
    <HasHeaders>true</HasHeaders>
    <IgnoreEmptyValues>true</IgnoreEmptyValues>
    <ImportDataDescription>Price List Data</ImportDataDescription>
    <ImportDataFileName></ImportDataFileName>
    <ImportDataType>MappedCSV</ImportDataType>
    <Passes>
        <DataImportPass z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
            <ConditionalSetters>
                <ConditionalDataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>EnteredBy</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>RecordDoesNotExist</_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>AutoImported</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </ConditionalDataSetter>
                <ConditionalDataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>EnteredOn</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>RecordDoesNotExist</_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>GetDate()    </_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </ConditionalDataSetter>
                <ConditionalDataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>LastModifiedBy</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>RecordAlreadyExists</_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>AutoImported</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </ConditionalDataSetter>
                <ConditionalDataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>LastModifiedOn</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>RecordAlreadyExists</_x003C_Condition_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>GetDate()    </_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </ConditionalDataSetter>
            </ConditionalSetters>
            <ListTypeId>14</ListTypeId>
            <LookupSetters />
            <Mappings>
                <DataMapping>
                    <_sourceAttemptsList>
                        <SourceAttempt>
                            <_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField     xmlns:d8p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                                <d8p1:string>Part No.</d8p1:string>
                            </_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField>
                        </SourceAttempt>
                    </_sourceAttemptsList>
                    <_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>    </_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>Optional</_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>     </_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>ItemCode</_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataMapping>
                <DataMapping>
                    <_sourceAttemptsList>
                        <SourceAttempt>
                            <_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField     xmlns:d8p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                                <d8p1:string>Order Code</d8p1:string>
                            </_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField>
                        </SourceAttempt>
                    </_sourceAttemptsList>
                    <_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>    </_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>Optional</_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>     </_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>Barcode</_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataMapping>
                <DataMapping>
                    <_sourceAttemptsList>
                        <SourceAttempt>
                            <_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField     xmlns:d8p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                                <d8p1:string>Description</d8p1:string>
                            </_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField>
                        </SourceAttempt>
                    </_sourceAttemptsList>
                    <_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>    </_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>Optional</_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>
                <_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>     </_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>SalesDescription</_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataMapping>
                <DataMapping>
                    <_sourceAttemptsList>
                        <SourceAttempt>
                            <_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField xmlns:d8p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                                <d8p1:string>Sale Price</d8p1:string>
                            </_x003C_SourceNames_x003E_k__BackingField>
                        </SourceAttempt>
                    </_sourceAttemptsList>
                    <_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>    </_x003C_DefaultValue_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>Optional</_x003C_Precision_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>     </_x003C_Separator_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>SalePrice</_x003C_TargetName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataMapping>
            </Mappings>
            <Name>Items</Name>
            <Parent i:nil="true" />
            <Passes />
            <Precision>Required</Precision>
            <Setters>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>AssetAccountId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>6</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>COGSAccountId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>9</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>ItemClassificationId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>2</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
            </DataSetter>
            <DataSetter>
                   <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>ItemGroupId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>-1</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>Keywords</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>    </_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>NormalTaxCodeId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>2</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>SalesAccountId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>22</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
                <DataSetter>
                    <_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>UnitOfMeasureId</_x003C_ColumnName_x003E_k__BackingField>
                    <_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>1</_x003C_Value_x003E_k__BackingField>
                </DataSetter>
            </Setters>
        </DataImportPass>
    </Passes>
    <PreserveSpaces>false</PreserveSpaces>
    <ProgressUnitType>CountOfTotal</ProgressUnitType>
    <Quote>34</Quote>
</DataImportConfiguration>
```

I am at a loss to understand this - there must be some difference between the machines, but what and where to find it?  I have done the following in my attempts to find a solution:

- checked to make sure there is not a .Net version problem
- checked to make sure that there is not an application or module version problem
- tried UTF-16 instead of UTF-8 (I know, clutching at straws!)
- tried messing with the namespace

Any suggestions or advice on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Open file with NotePad.  Then do SaveAs and check the encoding of the files in both machines.  Notepad has options for ANSI, UTF-8, Unicode.

Comment: Regrettably that made no difference.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Which encoding worked on good machine.

Comment: All of them!  The files contain only text anyway, so that is what I would expect...

Comment: Do you know what encoding is all about.  Text has different encoding schemes.

Answer (score 0):

This one turned out to be really simple - overactive code obfuscation was the cause.  The release version on the customer machine had obfucation in place which had affected the property name and therefore was causing the problem.

I proved this by deliberately loading an unprotected copy of the dll onto the customer's machine after which it all went exactly as expected.

The options in front of me now are:

1. Change the obfuscation settings
2. Decide not to obfuscate
3. Obfuscate ***before*** creating the XML file
4. Anything else I can come up with...

Thanks jdweng for the responses which were helpful in concentrating my thoughts as I looked for the answer.